# Unable to run coverity scan over the go language project

Tags: go, go-modules, coverity

I have pick on go open source to run coverity scan. I tried the following -

1. Download the coverity build tool for linux 64 (https://scan.coverity.com/download/other/linux64)
2. Set the path for coverity
3. Configure the go module in coverity by

   ```
    cov-configure --template --compiler go --comptype go
    cov-configure --template --compiler go-module --comptype go-module
   ```
4. Clone the open source repo in seperate folder
5. Now try to run cov build with the following command

   ```
   cov-build --config /home/vj202u/coverityScan/cov-analysis/config/coverity_config.xml --dir cov-int go build <open_source_project_folder_path>
   ```

Error Received -

> Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 2020.09 on Linux 5.4.0-67-generic x86_64
> Internal version numbers: 3412dc3383 p-upland-push-1502

> [ERROR] Build command not found. '.'

I tried to run cov-build with this also -

```
cov-build --dir cov-int --no-command --fs-capture-search .
```

[image]

Can somone suggest if i am missing anything? I don't find any doc to run it, please refer if you have any.

Comment: That error ("build command not found '.'") should not be possible from the `cov-build` command line shown (the one with "go build").  Please edit the question to contain the exact command you invoked and its result from the console.

Comment: Could you confirm if your native build is working ??
What is the exact build command you are passing for cov-build ?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the PATH=$PATH:/path/to/coverity/bin/folder

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.